# ¿Es necesario modificar bootstrap.min.css para agregar/hacer prevalecer mis estilos particulares?

Tags: bootstrap

En un proyecto en VS2013 de un website deseo modificar algunos atributos del diseño. Los cambios realizados en bootstrap.css en el inspector de páginas se muestran pero al publicar no aparecen el el site. Rascando descubrí que bootstrap.min.css también mantiene datos de css y esos son los que mandan.

Mis dudas son: ¿Hay que modificar los 2 css? ¿Por qué está todo en una sola línea? ¿Cómo hay que actuar?

Comment: no modifiques bootstrap.css, agrega otro css a la solución que modifique/pise los estilos de bootstrap.css.. sino deberás minimizar bootstrap.css (para crear bootstrap.min.css) cada vez que recompilas tu proyecto. esto hara mas lenta tu experiencia de desarrollo (por la carga extra). Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta lo que he cambiado en el boostrap.css es el color del menú superior, quiero aprovechar toda la funcionalidad y si como me indicas debo crear un css nuevo, como procedo quiero me conserve sus funcionalidades.

Comment: No modifiques `bootstrap.css`, a menos que uses las fuentes en less o sass (el nuevo estándar). Modificar `bootstrap.css` directamente es una **mala práctica** y debes evitarla. Modificar el archivo _minificado_ es todavía peor. La solución correcta es agregar tus modificaciones en otro archivo, como te lo indicó @rnd.

Answer (score 6):

Lo recomendable sería que **no modificases el archivo que te has descargado** de la página oficial. Llega un momento en el que no sabes cuáles son tus estilos y cuáles son los originales de Bootstrap y eso crea problemas de mantenimiento (especialmente si otro programador intenta seguir con el proyecto y asume que los estilos son los originales).

Lo que debes hacer es crear un fichero de CSS propio en el que se "sobreescriban" las reglas de Bootstrap que quieres cambiar. Así mantendrás la funcionalidad de Bootstrap pero con modificaciones tuyas.

Para que tus estilos tengan prioridad sobre los estilos por defecto de Bootstrap, tienes varias opciones:

1. **Escribe selectores más específicos**. La especificidad es el método que utilizan los navegadores para decidir qué estilos se van a aplicar cuando hay más de un selector definido para un elemento. Siguen una fórmula que calcula el valor de cada regla dando más puntos (prioridad) en este orden:

   - ID.
   - Clases y pseudo-clases.
   - Selectores de tipo y pseudo-elementos.

   Así si lo que quieres es que un `<nav>` tenga tus estilos en lugar de los de Bootstrap, puedes ponerle un atributo `id` y (re)definir los estilos sólo para ese id.
2. **Usa `!important`**. Cuando un estilo se define y se le añade `!important` al final, eso le dice al navegador que ese estilo tiene preferencia sobre cualquier otro (es más importante). Por ejemplo, aunque el estilo para `div` es menos específico que el de `div#azul`, se aplicará el color rojo porque esa propiedad viene con `!important`:

   ```
   <style>
   div {
       color: red !important;
   }
   div#azul {
       color: blue;
   }
   </style>
   <div id="azul">Este texto es rojo</div>
   ```

   Pero ojo **el uso de `!important` debería evitarse porque se considera mala práctica** como puedes leer en este [artículo de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepci%C3%B3n_!important). Si usas `!important` en todas partes, llega un momento en el que pierde su sentido y lo único que hace es agrandar tus ficheros de CSS y hacerlos más difíciles de leer y mantener.

Así que personalmente, **optaría por el primer método porque es más limpio**.

En ambos casos, también recomendaría que **el fichero CSS donde están tus estilos se incluya en el proyecto después de donde se incluyan los estilos de Bootstrap** (así, si dos selectores tienen igual valor de especificidad, tus estilos prevalecerán).

Answer (score 3):

Una buena práctica sería no modificar los estilos originales del proovedor (vendor) que este caso es Twitter con su librería Bootstra v3.x.

En la siguiente liga (español) se habla los selectores CSS y la jerarquía que hay entre las reglas para determinar cual tomar:

- [Capítulo 2. Selectores (Introducción a CSS) - LibrosWeb](http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_2.html)

#### En resumen:

> 1. Si existen reglas iguales, toma la última leída por el navegador (en un flujo de arriba para abajo), siempre y cuando una de ellas no tenga la propiedad **!important**.
> 2. Un regla con mayor especificidad tiene mayor prioridad que una que no la tiene.
>
> **Recomendacion:** Procura utilizar **!important** sólo como último recurso.

**Nota:** Antes de correr los ejemplos, mentalmente crea una solución (hipótesis) de lo que debería dar como resultado.

---

#### Ejemplo 1:

Un `<div>` con varias etiquetas de color aplicadas (notar el orden de las clases y definición de las reglas):

- ¿Qué color mostrará el texto?.

```css
.rojo { color: red; }
.azul { color: blue; }
.verde { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="azul verde rojo">Texto con color.</div>
```

#### Ejemplo 2:

Un `<div>` con varias etiquetas de color aplicadas (notar el order de las reglas en CSS):

- ¿Qué color mostrará el texto?.

```css
.verde { color: green; }
.color { color: blue; }
.color { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div class="color verde">Texto con color.</div>
```

#### Ejemplo 3:

Un `<div>` con varias etiquetas de color aplicadas (añadida especificidad a un color):

- ¿Qué regla da mayor especificidad que el resto?.
- ¿Qué color mostrará el texto?.

```css
div.rojo { color: red; }
.azul { color: blue; }
.verde { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="azul verde rojo">Texto con color.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `bootstrap.min.css` es la versión **"minimizada"** del archivo `bootstrap.css` y se genera automáticamente usando una herramienta (lo mas habitual hacerlo desde una tarea de [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/))

Lo que se suele hacer es que mientras se está desarrollando se usa la versión original y en producción la versión minimizada. Por ejemplo, basándose en la propiedad [`HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

En cuanto lo de personalizar la apariencia de Bootstrap te recomendaría que usarás la página [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). Desde esta página puedes configurar muchas opciones y después te descargas un zip con estas personalizaciones.

También puedes hacer lo que comenta [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro), añadiendo otro archivo `css` con reglas más específicas que sobrescriben los estilos por defecto.

Esto es muy potente porque puedes decorar el elemento principal con una clase que marcaría el "skin" y personalizar en base a ella los estilos de bootstrap

Archivo html:

```
<div class="skin-rob">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Archivo css:

```
.skin-rob .navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default {
    background-color: blue;
}

.skin-rob .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Esta modificación está haciendo que el fondo del "brand" del menú sea azul normalmente y rojo cuando está el ratón por encima (puedes verlo funcionando en [este](https://jsfiddle.net/vLvyhgtc/) JSFiddle)

Answer (score 0):

El mismo Bootstrap tiene una opción para personalizar los estilos de tu bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

En esta utilidad podrás cambiar lo que tu quieras de Bootstrap y al final generar tus archivos para utilizar en tu código. Con esto no tendrás que modificar manualmente el código generado.