# Eliminar estilos por defecto en Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Se que Boostrap viene con algunas clases en sus estilos por defecto y se que con mi propia hoja de estilos las puedo cambiar como yo quiera, pero lo que no se es ¿cómo borrar un atributo de estilo que viene por defecto en una clase?, puedo editarla pero no eliminarla.

Comment: Bienvenido @ISharkBlooDI a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: entra en la ruta de css de bootstrap y editas ahi el cod de su estilo es la unica forma ... sin o quieres "maquillar" el estilo q trae

Comment: Y si trabajo con CDN? no hay otra posibilidad o tengo que bajarme el css de Bootstrap?

Comment: Es interesante saber que en CSS [la propiedad de forma reducida all restaura todas las propiedades, excepto unicode-bidi y direction, a su valor inicial o heredado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/all). El [soporte en los navegadores de all](https://caniuse.com/#search=all) Si esto no ayuda por favor añade tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @IsharkBlooDi si quieres mantener el cdn tendrás que adjuntar una nueva hoja de estilos con los cambios necesarios para "chafar" los estilos de BS, pero no es una practica recomendable y suele ser dificil que no se te escape algo en alguna parte y no te des cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un enlace a una pregunta similar [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5468/es-necesario-modificar-bootstrap-min-css-para-agregar-hacer-prevalecer-mis-esti). Lee la respuesta de @Alvaro Montoro, que además de aclarar la duda que has planteado te aconseja la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Por si no te queda clara la explicación de Alvaro, y para contestar directamente a tu pregunta;

- Si que puedes editar/borrar los estilos que trae Bootstrap usando el lenguaje SASS por [ejemplo](https://styde.net/personalizar-bootstrap-4-en-laravel-con-sass-y-npm/). **Pero** no te aconsejo que lo hagas sin seguir antes un tutorial como el que te he dejado.
- La solución más "fácil" es sobrescribir estas clases que comentas en tu propia hoja de estilos, tal y como te explica Alvaro.

Espero que haber respondido a tu pregunta o al menos haberte aclarado algo. Para otra vez intenta definir mejor la estructura o poner algún ejemplo concreto para que se te pueda contestar mejor.

Un saludo!